# Refer to element element selector from another element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I use a css library (I cannot modify it).
It has a selector definition for textareas inside forms:

```
.ui.forms textarea { // some css }
```

Is there any way that I can apply this css to another element (e.g. a div or textarea outside a form)?

```
e.g. class =" .ui.forms textarea "
```

Comment: No, not with pure CSS. If possible you can add the `.ui.forms` classes to the parent of the element you want to style. Or use Javascript...

Comment: You can add custom css or not?

Comment: Yes. I can add my own css.

Comment: @LinkinTED: But then I have to add a surrounding div with the .ui.form class, right?

Comment: @obiwahn, yes, you will need to do that.